# Reorder the Ord of chars in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

Is there anyway I can adjust the `Ord` (order) of regular characters in a Haskell program such that `'a' > 'b'` ?

If not, do y'all have any suggestions on how I can best replicate this functionality? I tried `Data magicLetters = 'b' | 'a' | 'c' deriving (Show, Ord)`, but didn't get very far with that syntax.

Comment: Does it actually have to be `Char`, or are you using `Char` as a proxy for some other type, like `data MagicLetters = MLB | MLA | MLC deriving (Show, Ord)`?

Comment: @chepner well im reading the data in from file and therefore they come in as chars - it's as though I want to find the largest char (using my arbitrary order) from a file of random chars

Comment: Then your function to read the data should handle wrapping the input into your new type.

Comment: If you just want to reverse the ordering, you can use [`Down Char` instead of `Char`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base/docs/Data-Ord.html#t:Down).

Comment: If you need some custom ordering to get the largest, try `maximumOn` or `maximumBy` if friction of newtype wrapper is unwarranted.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Depending on why and how you're going to use it, you can try a wrapper-type:

```
newtype MyChar = MyChar Char

instance Eq MyChar where
    MyChar x == MyChar y = x == y

instance Ord MyChar where
    MyChar x <= MyChar y = x >= y   -- reverses the order
```

If you need a more specific logic, like `a > b`, but `b < c`, you may need some ordering table.

**EDIT**: As @leftaroundabout points out, the above already exists as [`Down`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Data-Ord.html#t:Down)

Comment: `MyChar ≅ Down Char`.